# Nuxt.js Store, dispatch action to other store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I have two stores on my Nuxt.js app and I need to dispatch an action to another store.

```
export const actions = {
   addToCart({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
    dispatch('CartLoadingStore/enableLoadingBar')

    this.$axios
      .post('something')
      .then(response => {
        (...)
        dispatch('CartLoadingStore/disableLoadingBar')
      })
  },
}
```

It seems to me like I cannot dispatch an action to a different store. Is that right? Or is there a way to do so?

The above will result in the error:

```
[vuex] unknown local action type: CartLoadingStore/enableLoadingBar, global type: StoreTheActionDispatchedFrom/CartLoadingStore/enableLoadingBar
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add root param to your dispatch call

```
dispatch('CartLoadingStore/disableLoadingBar', null, { root: true })
```

Here [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules)

Comment: Thanks Aldarund. Is there a documentation for this? Couldn't find anything in the nuxt docs..

Comment: @mauxtin i updated answer with link to docs. Since its vuex its stated in docs for vuex